# Jsf bean values setting to null instead of empty string

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF 1.2 Application and i use the following code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.countryType}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.allCounytryItems}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

When the user clicks on submit, the attribute of the bean 'countryType' is set to null instead of its default value as empty string ("").

For `<h:inputText id="username_label" value="#{MyBean.username}"/>`

The attribute username is set to empty string which is the default value.

Any inputs for the different behavior of the selectOneMenu ??

Comment: What is the initial value of countryType?

Comment: @Bogdan The initial value of countryType is null, but once we submit the form, it should set it with the default value as "". Am I missing some setting in web.xml?

Comment: Could you try to set itemValue as #{''}?